# using php to update a table based on dropdown selection

Tags: php

I have a php website I am building with a MySQL database.  I have a ticket system in place that works, but I want to add a drop-down selection menu (like a form input selection menu) that has three options: All, Open, Closed.

Based on the choice selected, I want it to update the shown tickets to only show what I have selected (all tickets, open tickets, or closed tickets, respectively) live (without having to hit a button, it just updates as soon as I select an option automatically).  I have spent the past 30 minutes to an hour searching around stackoverflow, google, and a few other places for information on how to do this, but it all related topics seem to relate to using javascript or AJAX (both of which I don't know how to code in, and javascript I am trying to keep off my site to avoid issues if a client has javascript disabled for their browser).

Is there a way to do this with only PHP, MySQLi, and HTML/CSS, or do I need to use javascript / AJAX to achieve this?

My Current code for updating my table as tickets are added:

```
function createTicket() {

require_once('config.inc.php');

// Connect to database
$mysqli = @new mysqli(DB_HOSTNAME,DB_USERNAME,DB_PASSWORD,DB_DATABASE);
// Check connection
if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
    printf("Unable to connect to database: $s", mysqli_connect_errno());
    exit();
}

$sql = "SELECT * FROM Tickets";
$result = $mysqli->query($sql);

$count = mysqli_num_rows($result);

$i = 0;

if (is_object($result) && $result->num_rows > 0) {
    while ($i<$count) {
        $sql2 = "SELECT * FROM Tickets WHERE id = ".$i;
        $tickets = $mysqli->query($sql2);
        $row = mysqli_fetch_array($tickets);

        // Set variables from query data        
        $ticketnum = $row['ticket'];
        $name = $row['name'];
        $email = $row['email'];
        $phone = $row['phone'];
        $address = $row['address'];
        $apt = $row['apt'];
        $city = $row['city'];
        $state = $row['state'];
        $zip = $row['zip'];
        $service = $row['service'];
        $detail = $row['detail'];
        $date = $row['reg_date'];
        $status = $row['status'];
        $tech = $row['tech'];

        // Create Table Row from variables
        echo "<tr><td>";
        echo "<a href='../ticket.php?ticketNum=".$ticketnum."'>".$ticketnum."</a>";
        echo "</td><td>";
        echo $status;
        echo "</td><td>";
        echo $service;
        echo "</td><td>";
        echo $date;
        echo "</td><td>";
        echo $tech;
        echo "</td></tr>";

        $i++;
        }
}

$mysqli->close();
}
```

And this is the code for the table itself:

```
<table id="tickettab">
<tr>
<td>
Ticket #
</td>
<td>
Status
</td>
<td>
Service-Type
</td>
<td>
Date Created
</td>
<td>
Tech Assigned
</td>
</tr>
<!-- New Row -->
<?php
createTicket();
?>
</table>
```

Comment: You can use onChange event for drop-down to refresh the page without Ajax.

Comment: Your code is very inefficient - there is no need to run a SELECT query for every ticket in the database. Select all the tickets and output them in a loop.

Comment: You can make the onChange either calls formname.submit() to refresh the page, or make it do an Ajax calls. (But you need a form, obviously.)

Comment: PHP runs server-side. You need something to happen client-side. This **will** require Javascript, though you can do it with or without Ajax, depending on the total number of items and performance requirements. Nobody has Javascript disabled nowadays.

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible without javascript. However, you don't need a lot of it.

First, your select drop-down list will look something like this; give it an *id*, so you can easily reference it:

```
<select id="filter">
    <option>All</option>
    <option>Closed</option>
    <option>Open</option>
</select>
```

Then produce your table. But don't perform a second query inside your loop. Instead loop over the results from your first query, using [`fetch_assoc`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.fetch-assoc.php), like this:

```
<?php
    ...
    if (is_object($result) && $result->num_rows > 0) {
        // Do not perform another SELECT, just iterate over the result set
        while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
            // Set variables from query data 
            $ticketnum = $row['ticket'];
            $name = $row['name'];
            $email = $row['email'];
            $phone = $row['phone'];
            $address = $row['address'];
            $apt = $row['apt'];
            $city = $row['city'];
            $state = $row['state'];
            $zip = $row['zip'];
            $service = $row['service'];
            $detail = $row['detail'];
            $date = $row['reg_date'];
            $status = $row['status'];
            $tech = $row['tech'];

            // Create Table Row from variables: 
            // Mark it with a custom data-status attribute
            echo "<tr data-status='$status'>";
            echo "  <td><a href='../ticket.php?ticketNum=$ticketnum'>$ticketnum</a></td>";
            echo "  <td>$status</td>";
            echo "  <td>$service</td>";
            echo "  <td>$date</td>";
            echo "  <td>$tech</td>";
            echo "</tr>";
        }
    }
?>
```

Note that in the above code the `TR` tag gets a custom attribute *data-status* set to the status value. This will make filtering of the row a lot easier.

Then, near the end of your HTML you should output the following `script` tag and code:

```
<script>
// Whenever the selection of the filter drop-down changes:
document.getElementById('filter').onchange = function() {
    // Get the selected filter value (Open, Closed, or All)
    var filter = this.value;
    // Iterate over all rows that have a data-status attribute
    [].forEach.call(document.querySelectorAll('tr[data-status]'), function (tr) {
        // Show/hide this row based on filter:
        tr.style.display = tr.getAttribute('data-status') === filter || filter == 'All'
            ? ''
            : 'none';
    });
}
</script>
```

Comments explain what happens. The filtering is performed using the custom *data-status* attribute you will have for each `TR` tag. If it matches with the selected filter value, or if the user selected "All", the corresponding row will be shown. Otherwise it is hidden, using the [*display: none* css style](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/display).

It is pure Javascript, no JS library is needed.

If however, you would use `jQuery`, then the above would be written as follows:

```
<script>
// Whenever the selection of the filter drop-down changes:
$('#filter').change(function() {
    // Get the selected filter value (Open, Closed, or All)
    var filter = this.value;
    // Iterate over all rows that have a data-status attribute
    $('tr[data-status]').each(function () {
        // Show/hide this row based on filter:
        $(this).toggle($(this).attr('data-status') === filter || filter == 'All');
    });
});
```

The advantage of a library like `jQuery` is that you have better support for older browsers. Notably the methods [`forEach`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach) and [`querySelectorAll`](https://developer.mozilla.org/nl/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll), used in the pure Javascript solution, are not supported in older browsers. And as a bonus, the code is shorter too.

In either case, there is no interaction with the server for applying the filter. It all happens on the client side.